# Random quotation mark being inserted into generated onclick html parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add parameters to an onclick function when generating HTML via javascript. When I inspect the code it is putting a quotation mark in the onclick function's parameter.

```
     var lengthOfCats = ArrayOfCategories.length;
     for (var a = 0; a < lengthOfCats; a++) {
     $("#CatTable").append("<div class='better-table-cell'>" + ArrayOfCategories[a].Name + "</div>\
                           <div class='better-table-cell'>" + ArrayOfCategories[a].DepartmentName + "</div>\
                           <div class='better-table-cell'>" + ArrayOfCategories[a].Active + "</div>\
                           <div class='better-table-cell'>\
                                <button onclick=OpenUpdateCat(" + ArrayOfCategories[a].CategoryID + "," + ArrayOfCategories[a].Name + ");" + ">Edit</button>\
                           </div>");
```

Here is an image of the HTML that is getting generated for the edit button.
[image]

Comment: You seems to have a problem with string encapsulation in general; the complete onclick attribute is not in `"` or `'`. Depending on the context, also `ArrayOfCategories[a].Name` should be enclosed by (escaped) quotation marks.

Comment: The browser is simply trying to correct your code's syntax errors.  You need to enclose HTML attributes in double-quotes, and you need to enclose JavaScript strings in either single-quotes or double-quotes.  You're not doing either of these things.

Comment: The screenshot you posted is 99% not the real source code generated: When strings+attributes are broken because of lacking `"` Firefox/Chrome tries its best to transform it to valid code, and the result is what you're seeing here in the DOM explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is normalising the HTML and putting quote marks around the attribute value.

The problem is that because the attribute value includes spaces, and you didn't put the quote marks in the right spots yourself, the attribute value finishes in the middle of the JavaScript.

The next bit of JS is then treated as a new attribute.

---

Mashing together strings to generate HTML is fundamentally a bad idea. Ensuring all the right things are quoted and escaped is hard.

Use DOM to generate your HTML instead.

It is a little longer, but clearer and easier to maintain in the long run.

```
var $cat_table = $("#CatTable");
var lengthOfCats = ArrayOfCategories.length;
for (var a = 0; a < lengthOfCats; a++) {
    $cat_table.append(
        $("<div />").addClass("better-table-cell").text(ArrayOfCategories[a].Name)
    );
    $cat_table.append(
        $("<div />").addClass("better-table-cell").text(ArrayOfCategories[a].DepartmentName)
    );
    $cat_table.append(
        $("<div />").addClass("better-table-cell").text(ArrayOfCategories[a].Active)
    );
    $cat_table.append(
        $("<div />").addClass("better-table-cell").append(
            $("<button />").text("Edit").on("click", generate_edit_handler(ArrayOfCategories[a].CategoryID, ArrayOfCategories[a].Name))
        )
    );
}

function generate_edit_handler(cat_id, name) {
    return function () {
        OpenUpdateCat(cat_id, name);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and for teaching me a more efficient way to write the code. Answered my question and taught me something new.